# Indy IdHttp, SSL and Proxy in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ssl, proxy, indy, idhttp

I use **Indy 10.6.2** with **Delphi 7**.

I must connect to a https server. I use this code :

```
FIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
FIdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
FIdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
FIdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
FIdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
FIdHTTP.IOHandler := FIdSSL;

FIdHTTP.Request.Clear;
FIdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
FIdHTTP.Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Basic xxxxxxx==';
FIdHTTP.Post(zURL, zJsonStreamIn, zJsonStreamOut);
finally
  zJSon := zJsonStreamOut.DataString;
end;
```

we have a proxy on lan : http://proxy-client.xxxxx.fr `Port : 8080`

I  use `proxyparams` :

```
FIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := 'http://proxy-client.in.ac-grenoble.fr';
FIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8080;
FIdHTTP.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
```

Then I have error 10001 (host not found) but when I  dont't use `proxyparams`, I have 10060.

Do you have any idea please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer` property expects just a hostname, not a full URL. Change this line:

```pascal
FIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := 'http://proxy-client.in.ac-grenoble.fr';
```

To this instead:

```pascal
FIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := 'proxy-client.in.ac-grenoble.fr';
```

---

On a side note:

You don't need the following lines, so you should remove them completely:

```pascal
FIdHTTP.Request.Clear;
FIdHTTP.Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Basic xxxxxxx==';
```

`TIdHTTP` has builtin support for `Basic` authentication. Simply set the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties as needed, and set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthorization` property to `True`.

Also, if you want the response data as a `string`, `TIdHTTP.Post()` has an overload for that purpose:

```pascal
zJson := IdHTTP.Post(zURL, zJsonStreamIn);
```

But either way, putting the call to `TIdHTTP.Post()` in a `try..finally` is good for cleanup, but if an HTTP error occurs, your `zJson` won't receive any data by default. If you need the response body for HTTP errors, you will need to either:

- catch the resulting `EIdHTTPProtocolException` and assign its `ErrorMessage` property to your `zJson` variable.
- enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, then `zJson` will receive both success and failure response bodies equally.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks' a lot for your help. I'll try this immediately.